# Display textbox message on the same page after form submission

Tags: php, textbox

I have a question about displaying textbox message on the top of the page.
I use this code -

```
 <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']=='Submit'){
 $message=$_POST['message'];
 $name=$_POST["name"];
 echo $name . "<br />" . $message;?>
 <html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
<form method="POST" action="<?=$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>">

    <br>Name:<input type="text" name="name" id="name">

    <br>Message:<textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea>

    <br><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>

   </form>
   </body>
   </html>
   <?php    
  }
  else {  
    ?>
 <html>
 <head>  
 </head>
 <body>
 <form method="POST" action="<?=$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>">

    <br>Name:<input type="text" name="name" id="name">

    <br>Message:<textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea>

    <br><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>

</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php } ?>
```

How can i save the previous entered details and display them below the new details submitted by the form

Comment: Perhaps append each message to the `$_SESSION` and display all messages in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass the previous message in an hidden field like this

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['prevmsg'])){

 echo "New Message :".$_POST['message'];
 echo "Previous Message :".$_POST['prevmsg'];

}

if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']=='Submit'){
 $message=$_POST['message'];
 $name=$_POST["name"];
 echo $name . "<br />" . $message;?>
 <html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
<form method="POST" action="<?=$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>">

    <br>Name:<input type="text" name="name" id="name">

    <br>Message:<textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea>
        <input type="hidden" name="prevmsg" value="<?=$message?>"/>
    <br><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>

   </form>
   </body>
   </html>
   <?php    
  }
  else {  
    ?>
 <html>
 <head>  
 </head>
 <body>
 <form method="POST" action="<?=$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>">

    <br>Name:<input type="text" name="name" id="name">

    <br>Message:<textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea>

    <br><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>

</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: It worked thank you. Just a bit messy going to sort it out. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

A dirty solution to keep you going...

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']=='Submit'){
  $message=$_POST['message'];
  $name=$_POST["name"];
  if( isset( $_COOKIE['previous_message'] ) ) {
    $the_previous = explode(';', $_COOKIE['previous_message']);
    echo $the_previous[0] . "<br />" . $the_previous[1];?>
  } else {
    setcookie('previous_message', $name . ';' . $message);
  }
  setcookie('previous_message', $name . ';' . $message);
  echo $name . "<br />" . $message;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Sibu, try this.

```
<?php
function display(){
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']=='Submit'){
        $message=$_POST['message'];
        $name=$_POST["name"];
        echo $name . "<br />" . $message;?>
    }
}
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php display(); ?>
<form method="POST" action="<?=$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>">
    <br>Name:<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    <br>Message:<textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea>
    <br><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

move the function so that you can specify where you want the message to be displayed. hope it helps.